# Xamarin deserialize Android.Runtime.JavaList

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I'm using xamarin, i'm trying, given a json string, to deserialize into a Android.runtime.JavaList using Newtonsoft Json. I think the json string is correct since it has been generated by newtonsoft json from the same JavaList, i just cant deserialize it again.
Everytime i try to deserialize i get this runtime error
`Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference` 
Here is my full method

```
public static Android.Runtime.JavaList<Order> unsent_orders = new Android.Runtime.JavaList<Order>();

public static string RestoreBackupOrders(string json, Context context) {
            if (json==null)
                return null;
            if (unsent_orders == null)
                return "NULL";
            unsent_orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Android.Runtime.JavaList<Order>>(json);
            return json;
        }
```

The error is generated by this line

```
unsent_orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Android.Runtime.JavaList<Order>>(json);
```

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Please use `System.Collections.Generic.List<Order>` to replace the `Android.Runtime.JavaList<Order>` in the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(json)`.

Comment: I would but in that case NotifySetDataChange method doesnt refresh my listview

Comment: I tried to change to System.Collections.Generic.List<Order> but i get the same error

Comment: Can you share simiple of Json type that I can test it. `NotifySetDataChange method doesnt refresh my listview` Please make sure if you use same list between Listview and Adapter. Share this part of code may be helpful to solve this issue.